# Complete Graph Decomposition with Copies of Given Graph

Tags: graph-theory

Let $K_n$ be the complete graph with $n$ vertices. Let $G$ be any connected graph with $n$ vertices. Finally, let $G_i$ be a graph with the same topology as $G$ but with a permutation of some vertices.

Is there any theoretical result on the minimum number of $G_i$'s needed to sum to obtain the $K_n$? Or should I analyze the different types of graphs (i.e. grids, stars, Hamiltonian paths, etc) separately? I know the result using Hamiltonian paths as a decomposition, but I am struggling with a general answer.

As an example:
[Decomposition of $K_4$ using a given graph structure.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FWlWX.png)

Comment: Have you heard of graph packing?

Comment: For trees, ringel's conjecture was solved recently, https://www.quantamagazine.org/mathematicians-prove-ringels-graph-theory-conjecture-20200219/

Comment: @Hendrix thanks I didn't know about it! I've been doing some research but all I can find is for cases where the number of vertices is different or there are no edges repeated. In my case, I need both $G$ and $K_n$ to have the exact same vertices and is not a problem if an edge is repeated, since this will imply that the weight of that edge, in the $K_n$ graph, will be the original value times the number of repeatition.

Comment: @ThomasLesgourgues thanks for the answer! I will look into it, but it seems that this conjecture uses smaller graphs to pack a complete graph with more vertices. As I said in the previous comment, I am looking for packing a complete graph with any graph with the same number of vertices, but I don't know if such result exists...